# How to test an Express application when using app.use(express.static('public'));

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, testing, jestjs

I am unable to mock  app.use(express.static('public'));
All of my test have worked before i added this line in. I have tested express servers previously using the same approach, however, this is the first time i've used this express.static command.

After adding this line of code in i now get this error in my tests -

```
TypeError: _express.default.static is not a function
```

All of my tests pass if i remove the line of

```
  app.use(express.static('public'));
```

However, i need this line as i serve up some static images in my app elsewhere.

I have mocked Express as shown in the code below, however, express is a function that returns an Object, this is then used to mock the get(), use() and listen() calls.

Now that i have added express.static('public') it looks like express is also a static object now.

So i need to  adjust the

```
jest.mock('express', () => ....
```

section?

Just not sure how to mock this line - app.use(express.static('public'));

Express - Server.js File

```
const start = () => {
  const port = process.env.port || 7000;
  const app = express();

  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(cors());
  app.use(express.static('public'));
...
}

Test -  Server.test.js File 


jest.mock('express', () =>
  jest.fn(() => ({
    get: jest.fn(),
    use: jest.fn(),
    listen: jest.fn()
  }))
);

jest.mock('body-parser', () => ({
  json: jest.fn()
}));

jest.mock('cors');

describe('app set up correctly ', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
    server.start();
  });

  it('should initialise express server', () => {
    expect(express).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

I hope to amend the mock call to mock the static call so i no longer get this error 
TypeError: _express.default.static is not a function
and my other tests pass as expected

Any help anyone can give is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `express` is a function that has properties.  So, if you're trying to mock it, you will have to mimic both the behavior of the function and of whatever properties are used.

Comment: @jfriend00 do you have an example of how to do that for the express.static('public')) ? 
I have mocked the express properties for get use and listen. But i don't know what alternation needs to be made to my mock above to also mock for express.static.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know jest to know how you would do that in jest.

Answer (score 2):

This should mock the `express.static` method:

```
jest.mock('express', () => {
  const mockedExpress = () => {
    return {
      get: jest.fn(),
      use: jest.fn(),
      listen: jest.fn(),
    }
  };
  Object.defineProperty(mockedExpress, "static", { value: jest.fn() });
  return mockedExpress;
});
```